# How to set up aliases in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I know that in bash you can set up aliases in a `.bash_aliases` file, so that the command you type doesn't need to be a command stored in the binaries in the system.  Is there any way I can get aliases into `zsh`?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can do it by the "alias" command with this syntax:

```sh
alias [ -gmrL ] [ name[=value] ... ]
```

For "gmrL" switches, see [this guide, which is my reference](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Aliasing).
For each name, with no value, zsh will print the name and what it is aliased to previously. With no arguments at all, `alias` prints the values of ALL defined aliases.

To define one or more aliases, simply enter:

```sh
alias name1=value1 name2=value2 ... nameX=valueX
```

For each name with a corresponding value, zsh defines an alias with that value. For further info, check out that link. ;-)

Comment: That document answered my question exactly.  Thanks much.

Comment: That link is down.

Comment: updated the link.

Comment: this answer misses the part about where to persist the aliases, Kurtosis answer includes it (.zshrc).

Comment: I use `~/.profile` to store all aliases I care about and source `~/.profile` it from `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: I tried to store all my aliases in `~/.zprofile` but most are overwritten @danba

Answer (score 209):

I go back and forth between bash and zsh, and use the same `.aliases` file for both. They share the same basic alias syntax, so you can create a [`.aliases` file](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/main/.aliases) and link it to `.bashrc` and `.zshrc`:

#### .bashrc

```sh
if [ -f ~/.aliases ]; then
    . ~/.aliases
fi
```

#### .zshrc

```sh
source $HOME/.aliases
```

FWIW this can also be done with environment variable declarations, in a separate [`.env` file](https://github.com/byrongibson/dotfiles/blob/master/.env).

Comment: I just added source ~/ .bash_aliases to the end of .zshrc, so all aliases are working both on bash and zsh

Comment: @talsibony 
 
like this: `~/ .bash_aliases` I need little help please if you are there, respond

Comment: @lewis4u There should not be a space between ~/ and .bash_aliases.  It should be exactly ~/.bash_aliases.

Comment: Your links are broken..

Comment: Both links are broken. Wouldn't both the same as `[ -r "$HOME/.aliases" ] && source "$HOME/.aliases"`? ([nice doc](https://scriptingosx.com/2019/07/moving-to-zsh-part-4-aliases-and-functions/))

Answer (score 12):

You generally put them in `~/.zshenv`.  But many programs use `/bin/sh` (usually `bash`) instead of `$SHELL` to execute shell commands, so for it to work everywhere you will probably need to put the `bash` equivalent of the alias into `~/.bash_aliases` anyway.

Comment: This is for my user account only, so this does not need to be copied to the ~/.bash_aliases file.

Comment: According to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71253/what-should-shouldnt-go-in-zshenv-zshrc-zlogin-zprofile-zlogout), aliases should go in `.zshrc` because `.zshenv` is "Read every time" -- "this file is read even when Zsh is launched to run a single command."

Comment: As `.zshenv` is always sourced, the aliases would even affect scripts, so this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying some things and I found a way to use my aliases created in bash into zsh, only I had to copy these lines from bashrc:

```
if [ -e ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
  . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

## `.zshrc`

add this line at the bottom of the file (**assuming that your aliases located in `~/.profile`**):

```
source ~/.profile
```

Comment: Don't do this. Depending on what's in `~/.profile`, you might end up with weird errors or, worst case, an unusable shell, since `~/.profile` in turn sometimes calls another shell's rc file (e.g. you could end up with a circular reference). Also `~/.profile` is meant to be executed once per login, not once per terminal process. I would source `~/.bash_aliases` or `~/.aliases` (whichever exists) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone find this useful: My situation is that I have a Macbook Laptop, Ubuntu Laptop, Ubuntu Desktop and couple of Ubuntu VMs. In all of them I want to use defaults (so Bash in Ubuntu and Zsh in OSX) but with same aliases.

The way I handle it is that I have my alias file `.bash_aliases` in git repo called `dotfiles`. I just clone the repo in all my computers and I just create a symlink to the alias file:

```
ln -s "~/wherever_i_store_git_repos/dotfiles/.bash_aliases" "~/.bash_aliases"
```

in Ubuntu I add this to `~/.bashrc` :

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
  . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

in OSX I add this to `.zshrc` :

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
  source $HOME/.bash_aliases
fi
```

> note: Alternatively if you don't use git you can ln -s a  Dropbox folder

Answer (score 0):

What I've found from [official guide](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide02.html#l22) for Zsh it could be done by code below in your `.zshrc`:

> ```
> if [[ -r ~/.aliasrc ]]; then
>     . ~/.aliasrc
> fi
> ```
>
> which checks if there is a readable file `~/.aliasrc`, and if there is, it runs it in exactly the same way the normal startup files are run. You can use `source` instead of `.` if it means more to you; `.` is the traditional Bourne and Korn shell name, however.

Answer (score -2):

I wrote this and put it in my `~/.bashrc` a long time ago. I didn't put all that can be done with saving your settings, but just use your imagination!

Note: If you're updating `~/.bash_aliases` then update `~/.oh-my-zsh/.zsh_aliases` too.

Saves your `~/.bash_history`, `~/.bashrc`,  `~/.bash_aliases` and `~/.profile` in Dropbox. First make a file named after your files in the Dropbox folder. That way no matter where you edit it, if it's edited?  It's up-to-date on all you devices. Add the following lines in your `~/.bashrc` :

```
    DBPATH=${HOME}"/Dropbox"; ## Path to your DropBox Folder
if [ -d "${DBPATH}" ] 
then
 
    BA="/.bash_aliases" ## Path to your .bash_aliases File
if [ ${HOME}"${BA}" -nt ${DBPATH}"${BA}" ] 
then
    cat ${HOME}"${BA}" > ${DBPATH}"${BA}" 2>/dev/null;
# If updating ~/.bash_aliases then update ~/.oh-my-zsh/.zsh_aliases Too
    cat ${HOME}"${BA}" > ${ZSH}"/.zsh_aliases" 2>/dev/null;
 fi

    BRC="/.bashrc"  ## Path to your .bashrc File
if [ ${HOME}"${BRC}" -nt ${DBPATH}"${BRC}" ] 
then
    cat ${HOME}"${BRC}" > ${DBPATH}"${BRC}" 2>/dev/null;
 fi
 
    BPF="/.profile" ## Path to your bash .profile File
if [ ${HOME}"${BPF}" -nt ${DBPATH}"${BPF}" ] 
then
    cat ${HOME}"${BPF}" > ${DBPATH}"${BPF}" 2>/dev/null;
 fi

    BHT="/.bash_history"    ## Path to your .bash_history File
if [ ${HOME}"${BHT}" -nt ${DBPATH}"${BHT}" ] 
then
    cat ${HOME}"${BHT}" > ${DBPATH}"${BHT}" 2>/dev/null;
 fi
## First make a file named after your files in the Dropbox folder
# That way no matter where you edit konsole bookmarks, If it's edited? 
# It's up-to-date on all Your devices.
    HLS=${HOME}"/.local/shere"
    KBM="/konsole/bookmarks.xml"
if [ ${HLS}"${KBM}" -nt ${DBPATH}"${KBM}" ] 
 then
        cat ${HLS}"${KBM}" > ${DBPATH}"${KBM}" 2>/dev/null;
    fi
fi
```

Comment: your solution is for Bash, not ZSH.  ZSH has its own RC file